# Is there any way to add photos to a fillable PDF from storage on the go?

Tags: javascript, pdf

I'm trying to add photos to a PDF fallable form. Photos are coming from a scanner and being saved inside a specific folder. In the PDF file, there are placeholders for every photo. What I'm trying to achieve is, to add photos to placeholders as soon as the scanner creates in the folder.

I'm using Javascript inside a PDF. I'm able to add photos from the folder in those placeholders. But apparently, there is no option to poll that folder for new photos.

Comment: What code are you writing to do this and where you are getting struck

Comment: Post what code you have written so far.

Comment: Javascript. I'm able to add photos from the folder in those placeholders. I just can't seem to figure out a way to scan the folder for new files. I can only add those ones that are already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. There is no way you can make a recursive call in PDF script.